# How to simply animate views in android

Tags: java, android, animation, view

I've been looking around the web and also on the developer guide for Android but couldn't find any SIMPLE way to animate my views sequentially as I want.
I'd like to be able to execute several animations like this

```
yourView.animate().xBy(100).setDuration(500);
yourView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500);
yourView.animate().whateverIwannaDo(...).setDuration(...);
...
```

with (or without) a waiting time between each animation and without having to use AnimatorSet or AnimationSet (which I don't understand even after reading the developer guide) :/

If there is no way to do so then would there be any clear guide which would explain step by step how to use AnimatorSet and all that.

I hope you guys will be indulgent in relation to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to use [NineOldAndroid](http://nineoldandroids.com). It’s a library that allow to use Honeycomb animation API  for all versions of the Android platform.

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationX", 0, 360),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "translationX", 0, 90),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleX", 1, 1.5f),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", 1, 0.25f, 1));
set.setDuration(5 * 1000).start();
```

To use this library you have three options:

With `gradle`, in your build.gradle configuration file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Using `maven`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, you can add it to your project as a [dependency jar](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/downloads)

Comment: Sure that's exactly what I wanted to understand. The "ObjectAnimator.ofFloat" part. Now I'm good.
So what do I gotta do if I wanna use this library ?